# Changing database version in Visual Web Developer 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-web-developer

Using Visual Web Developer 2008 which comes with SQL Server 2008 by default. Is there a way to change a SQL2008 database to SQL2005 version from within Visual Web Developer?

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Trying to change the DB version from 2008 to 2005 from within VWD

Answer (score 0):

**SSMS**
[How to: View or Change the Compatibility Level of a Database (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx)

**EDIT:**
Since you don't have SSMS (why not?) you can also issue this command to set the compatibility of a database to SQL 2005.

```
ALTER DATABASE [DATABASE_NAME] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
```

Comment: the environment does not have SQL Server Management Studio installed. I know, right? Needs to be done within VWD.